# How to attatch a bufferedInputStream to a string?

Tags: java, buffer, inputstream

Basically, I'm trying to automate keystrokes by switching an existing BufferedInputStream(System.in) to my own buffered input stream.  I would like to make a BufferedInputStream() object that attaches to something like a string which can be controlled asynchronously.

Here's what I'd like to do..

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder;
BufferedInputStream output=new something(new something(stringBuilder));
```

Currently the only option I can see is to check if a file exists, then open a buffered input stream to it.

I'm not really sure how to do this, but I need to write to something which can take the place of the System.in inpustream.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Do you want to write to `output` or read from it?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do either. Do you want to write to the StringBuilder and then later read what you wrote from the InputStream?

Comment: Basically, I've got a large program which I need to sometimes be part of a larger program.  So, i'm hyjacking stdin and stdout from the original program and redirecting into readers/writers :)  Answer is below, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put a good solid  10 hours into this... here's what I came up with..   Piped Streams are what i need

```
    int BUFFER = 4096;
    PipedOutputStream toAppPipedOutputStream;
    PipedInputStream toAppPipedInputStream;

    static BufferedReader fromAppBufferedReaderfinal;
    BufferedOutputStream fromAppOutputStream;
    PipedOutputStream fromAppPipedOutputStream;
    PipedInputStream fromAppPipedInputStream;

    /* constructor sets up logging and parameters */

           try { 
                fromAppPipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream(BUFFER);
                fromAppOutputStream=new BufferedOutputStream(new PipedOutputStream(fromAppPipedInputStream));
                fromAppBufferedReaderfinal=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fromAppPipedInputStream));
                CASUAL.Log.out = new PrintStream(fromAppOutputStream);

                toAppPipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream(BUFFER);
                toAppPipedOutputStream=new PipedOutputStream(toAppPipedInputStream);
                CASUAL.CASUALInteraction.in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(toAppPipedInputStream));
```

In my log and output classes I am, by default, writing into a buffered reader/writer that is pointing at System.in.  I can hyjack it because it's a public static and this is possible.  Now I can just read and write to my app as though it were running on the command line inside my own app